# Redirect microphone input to headphone output (soft playthru)

Tags: cocoa, applescript, microphone, headphones

If I use my in-ear headphones with my macbook pro it takes me a few minutes until they are fitting perfectly (due to the foam bits on the headphones) :)

My idea is to use internal macbook pro microphone to be able talk to somebody coming to my desk without having to remove the headphones every time. So kind of an 'intercom' thing which can be enabled by hitting a hotkey.

First thought was to use applescript which could be easily used for pausing iTunes, but I could not find information about how I could forward the microphone output to my headphones.

Next try was to check Xcode for writing a Cocoa App. By starting with an example provided by Apple I think it would be achievable for me to extend it to fit my needs.

So my question is:
Do you have a better idea/approach to solve my problem?

Comment: You want to redirect the microphone input to the headphone output without any delay, right? Changed title for clarity.

Comment: [LineIn](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/) provides soft playthru, no need to code it yourself :)

Comment: that fits my needs. Thanks Anne

Comment: @Anne: would you mind putting that recommendation into an answer, so that OP can accept it and we can get this off the unanswered list?