# How to record in real time the audio sounds and then play them with the in-built speakers or headphones in iOS?

Tags: xcode, audio, real-time, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I want to build an iOS app using AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer simoultaneously. Something like a megaphone that records in real time voices and sounds in the ambient and play them all in real time, without any type of sound processing. I want to create a temporary file with a single button start/stop. Suggestions? How can I do?

Comment: something like this (LineIn: http://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/) answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191285/redirect-microphone-input-to-headphone-output-soft-playthru ?

Comment: No, I want to make something on iOS, with the build-in iphone microphone and the speakers! all recorded and played at real time, but at different volumes! The iphone may be connected to a stereo and can be used as a megaphone or simply, like a microphone.